# Launch Labview program through Python

Tags: python-3.x, activex, labview

I am working on a project in which I have to launch a VI (Labview program) through my `GUI` written in python. I have not the administrator rights so I installed PyCharm Community with the JetBrain Toolbox and `Python 3.3` with an `MSI` file.

I read on the internet that to do what I want, I need to install the pywin32 extension: [extension -link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/?source=navbar), but when I launch it, it doesn't find my Python installation.

So, my question is: is there another way to control VI from python?

Thank you in advance for your answer. I am a beginner in both languages.

Comment: It is okay. I finally succeeded. Creating 2 threads with one launching the VI and the other running the python code to get some datas with TCPIP communication.

Comment: I once did it the other way around, calling the python script using LabVIEW's [System Exec](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/8E19CA81874FFDD786256BE40066C151) - one of the arguments is whether to wait for completion or not. I also use the System Exec to list all processes before and after calling the python script, so I can get it's process number and kill it (again with System Exec) through LabVIEW if it's taking too long.

Comment: berna, I prefer launch a LabVIEW Vi from Python because I am better in Python than LabVIEW. And because I have to deal with threads and timer in my Python script. But thank you for telling me it is possible in this way too.

Comment: Have you tried [PyVISA](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? It might lack LabVIEW's GUI, but it should replace the need to use it if it's only being used to talk to devices.

Comment: I haven't to talk devices, only send/receive data between LabVIEW and Python ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to run a plain VI, you have to run the LabVIEW IDE -- a
  VI is a source code file, not a built executable, so to run directly,
  it has to be hosted in the editor.
- If you want to run a VI built into
  an executable, you obviously have to run that built EXE.

So, either way, you're going to have to be able to launch an EXE.

Can your Python invoke C-style DLLs? If so, you could build your VI into a DLL and then call the VI that way.

Comment: For now I am working with a VI. But at the end, it will be compiled into an executable.
For now, I launch a VI using the win32com dll in Pyhton and I can "Call" or "Run" the VI but it is not what I want because I would like just to launch the VI and execute the python code after the calling and like this the two codes execute in the same time. But here Python wait the end of the VI execution to continue its script. Maybe I understood something wrong, I thought that it was possible to execute Python code and VI in the same time (I am doing this with server/client communication for example).